# MongoDB non-relational db problems?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have knowledge with mysql but I am trying to learn/understand mongodb, problems I encounter so far is idea of non-relational db. There is no join and this is kinda bugging (however i understand why). What I would like you to answer me is the sollution to following problem:

Lets say we have posts and comments. We create two objects in mongodb and if we want to display comment by certain user on certain post we just query each and then combine tables by id. What I dont understand is what happens if user that already commented on couple of posts changes his nickname. How would we then fix that. Do i have to change all posts and comments user ever commented on?

db schema:

```
POSTS
    text
    id

COMMENT
    text
    post_id
    author_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think you're asking the right questions.  You are right in that, as a non-relational database, MongoDB isn't going to manage issues with referential integrity for you. If there is truly an issue of referential integrity, this can post a bit of a headache, because you'll find yourself in potential situations where you'll have lots of documents to update should one of your users modify a piece of information that you've stored across all your documents. Let's take your example, except translated into what I would normally expect as a first attempt at how you might set it up on MongoDB...

```
db.posts.save({
    author:"susan@yahoo.com",
    name:"Susan Person",
    text:"This is my first post. Isn't it fancy?",
    comments:[
         { author:"john@google.com", name:"John", text:"What a great post!" },
         { author:"sally@email.com", name:"Sally", text:"You really put some thought into this." }
    ]
});

db.authors.save({
    _id:"susan@yahoo.com",
    name:"Susan Person",
    favorite_icecream:"Chocolate",
});
```

I fleshed things out a little more than your example, but I'm hoping this will help you see what I'm about to say.

So.  Without sounding overly Zen, I think the only way to answer your question is to ask another question: *Do you really need to update all the existing comments with a new nickname?*

In my experience, the answer is probably no.  If the original author (Susan in this case) of the post changed their username, however, you may want to.  So how do you do that?  You modify the authors document first, then you select all documents with { author:"susan@yahoo.com" } and update the author on those posts.

Use your experience and your knowledge of how the system is going to be *used* in order to decide on your schema.  If you truly need to ensure that the comment's name reflects an entry in the authors collection, you will have to do the extra legwork for all of them as well.

There are some more advanced solutions to your question as well. You may, for example, decide that you need quick access to the first 10 comments on a post, and after that you can afford to make the user wait while you asynchronously pull the rest of them out of the database and do the relevant matches to pull the data together.  In that case, your schema would look similar to the above, but you wouldn't store more than 10 comments with the name copied onto them on the post, and you might store all the remaining comments in an additional collection which only reference the users e-mail. Then, when you go to find the comments you can do a second query against the email in the users collection and ensure you are getting the most up-to-date name.  Over time, comments will scroll, and unless a post is stale and never receives any additional comments (I would argue this means nobody cares that their name has been updated), it will eventually achieve referential integrity with the rest of the db.

For a much more detailed comparison of the different options you might want to choose, see the following link:

http://www.alvinonmongodb.com/2012/07/schema-design-3-embedding-versus.html

As the author of the article states:

> The question is not really embedding or linking, it should be "what's
>   my use case and access patterns". If you know that, then the decision
>   of embedding, linking or a hybrid model is simpler to make.

Comment: thank you for that answer. About comment author name: this was just example (and I agree if name stayed unchanged this wouldnt be such a big deal...but I just wanted to know the idea behind it, because there are cases when you need to change some data of user.) however you answered my question realy well.... My conclusion: MongoDB is great but if you need a lot of relations between tables can be harder than mysql (and probably slower too)

Comment: I think you're conclusion is a good one. 

One way to think of it is this: If your application needs your data to  maintain a lot of relationships and cross references, MongoDB may not be the best solution for you.  Or, as we do at my company, you may choose to store some parts of your application in a relational database and the less structured data in Mongo.

Mongo's (and noSQL in general's) strength lies in its ability to scale horizontally and vertically. If you don't need that kind of scale, then you may not need MongoDB. It depends on how much data you're expecting to have to store.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve what you want:

- **Use the _id instead of the name**: This one is almost the same as a foreign key in SQL, but you don't have any checks if the related object exists and so on. Of course if you want to show the username, you would have to query for each username. Using this means overhead, but if you don't have a high load on your MongoDB, it should not be very much. Even better, depending on how much users you got, you can make an index on id and username so the username stays in RAM, meaning the read will be lightning fast.
- **Update all comments**: You can update all comments for a certain username after renaming it. For this to work you might want to store the user_id beside the username inside your comment collection, then query for the id and change the username. I guess MongoDB has ways for doing this fast.
- **Use embedded collections**: There are embedded collections in MongoDB, which solve some of those problems and create others. You don't want to embed a user inside a comment, but for other use cases this is very handy. I am just mentioning it here.

**Working with MongoDB**

The overall problem is, that when using a NoSQL Database, you have to think about your use cases. It's not that "we normalize our data and then see how we write our queries" but rather "we want to use the data this and that way, how do we need to store the data". So, from the above, there might be other solutions which might be more handy.

Maybe it's using a special id with the username in front (remember, the id can be anything) and then using the application to extract the username. Or maybe it's keeping a dublicated collection of somekind of merged document where comments and user information are stored together beside their own collections, which can get regenerated if something changes.

It takes some time to get used to this way of working, but you'll get used to it. If you're just starting, you are probably not developing a platform with 100000 hits a second, so you can just store the object id and do a second query on that id to get the username when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was a relational database that is not a great schema. You would use author_id on the comment document instead of author_name. This id would be unique for that user. Then you create a single user document that relates author_name and author_id.

Now when you change the author ne it only happens in one document.

Comment: it was just to ilustrate an example of the problem it wasnt really the best schema.